# Google Contacts API - PostalAddress Country not working set value

Tags: c#, .net, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to set the value in "PostalAddress Country," but that does not change the country in Google Contacts. Always define Portugal (my country that I live in).
I'm using .NET C#:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
```

I've tried several options:

```
StructuredPostalAddress postalAddress = new StructuredPostalAddress();

postalAddress.Country = new Country("SZ").Value;
//OR
postalAddress.Country = "SZ";
//OR
postalAddress.Country = "Suisse";
//OR
postalAddress.Country = "États-Unis";
//OR
postalAddress.Country = "Unites States"; //The same exemple in doc Google API

contact.PostalAddresses.Add(postalAddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think the issue are not set properties of postal adress. Set all necessary properties. This is my code:

```
StructuredPostalAddress CreateNewPostalAdress(CIAdress cia)
    {
        // neue Adresse anlegen
        StructuredPostalAddress newPostalAdress = new StructuredPostalAddress()
        {
            Rel = GetRelationShip(cia.RelationShip), 
            Primary = false,   
            Street = cia.Street,
            City = cia.City,
            Region = cia.Region,
            Postcode = cia.Postcode,
            Country = cia.Country,
        };
        return newPostalAdress;
    }
```

`cia.Country` is a string value. Try it with `United States` as value. If this is working you can expand with your code.